# Equally space columns with a table layout

Tags: android

When I'm trying to do a neat table layout in android, and try to space the columns equally, all I get is this.

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/1070xtw.png]

I cannot for the life of me equally space those columns out.

Comment: you should also post your table.xml file content

Comment: Please post your XML layout. You should be able to do what you want with LinearLayout and weight. TableLayout has the strechColumn property which imght help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong the [`android:stretchColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android%3astretchColumns) attribute. As you can see in the documentation it is the `zero-based index` of the column to stretch. So you want to stretch the first column, you should use :

```
 android:stretchColumns="0"
```

in yout `TableLayout`.

Comment: That was it, thanks. I should've tried this before fiddling with paddings and margins..